# Validate elements in a collection, return Failure for first invalid element

Tags: scala

If I have some validation function:

```
def validateOne(a: A): Try[A]
```

And I now want to validate a collection of A by using the `validateOne` function

```
def validateAll(all: List[A]): Try[List[A]]
```

Is there a nice way to return a `Failure` as soon as the first element is found to be invalid?

The way I'm doing it now is by calling `get` after validating each element. For the first element where `validateOne` returns `Failure`, `get` throws the wrapped exception...which I catching re-wrap:

```
def validateAll(all: List[A]): Try[List[A]] = try {
  all.map(a => validateOne(a).get)
} catch {
  case e: MyValidationException => Failure(e)
}
```

Comment: `Try(all.map(a => validateOne(a).get))` Will make the trick as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could easily transform `List[Future[A]]` to `Future[List[A]]` with [Future.sequence](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-reactive-programming/9781787288645/e98e36fe-db95-4bea-98d2-bf2e6eb809e0.xhtml). Unfortunately the standard library doesn't provide a similar method for `Try`.

But you could create your own tail-recursive, failing fast function to iterate over results:

```
def validateAll[A](all: List[A]): Try[List[A]] = {

  //additional param acc(accumulator) is to allow function to be tail-recursive
  @tailrec
  def go(all: List[A], acc: List[A]): Try[List[A]] =
    all match {
      case x :: xs =>
        validateOne(x) match {
          case Success(a) => go(xs, a :: acc)
          case Failure(t) => Failure(t)
        }
      case Nil => Success(acc)
    }

  go(all, Nil)
}
```

If you're using [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) in your stack you could also use traverse (traverse is map + sequence):

```
import cats.implicits._

def validateAll2[A](all: List[A]): Try[List[A]] = all.traverse(validateOne)
```